# Ember.js - Multiple App.deferReadiness() and App.advanceReadiness() calls

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I am trying to run two initilizers in my application.

The first is a Socket.io connection which opens a Socket and then shares it to the other initialiser and all controllers/routes.

The second is a session system which deals with cookie storage and pulling down the users profile in to the Store.

What I would like to do is use App.deferReadiness() in the first initialiser and App.advanceReadiness() in the second initilizer. This is where the problem lies.

If I put the App.deferReadiness() call in the first initilizer and the App.advanceReadiness() in the other one the app doesn't start.

If I use a matching pair of App.deferReadiness() and App.advanceReadiness() in both files I get an error which says the "ready hook has already been called". (this comes from the second initilizer).

What am I doing wrong?

Note: I didn't post code samples as I didn't think they would be needed for this. If they are, let me know.

**Update**

/initializers/socket.js

```
/* Socket Initaializer */
var Initaializer = {
    name: 'Socket',
    initialize: function(Container, App) {

        App.deferReadiness();

        /* Open Socket.IO Connection  */


    }
};
```

/initializers/session.js

```
/* Export */
export default Initaializer;


/* Session Initaializer */
var Initaializer = {
    name: 'Session',
    after: 'Socket',
    initialize: function(Container, App) {  

        // Session Code Here

        App.advanceReadiness();


        // Nothing Happens After This....

    }
};

/* Export */
export default Initaializer;
```

Comment: You have to call `Ember.Application.initializer();`.

Comment: @jpreynat - where do I need to call this?

Comment: Instead of `var Initaializer = { name: ... };`, use `Ember.Application.initializer({ name: ... });`

Comment: I am using ES6 modules so I need to export it rather than use the Global Var.

Comment: @jpreynat - if it helps, I am calling the application.advanceReadiness(); inside of an Ember.Object. Is this important? Do Ember.Objects not get ran when the app start is deferred?

Comment: What's the code in your `app/app.js`? You should have something like that: `import Initaializer from 'appkit/initializers/socket'; ... (same for session) ...
Ember.Application.initializer(Initaializer);`. Then the problem is that your initializers have the same name.

Comment: @jpreynat You shouldn't need to import the initilizers in to app.js as the resolve deals with that. I have fixed this by calling App.advanceReadiness(); outside of an Ember.Object. It seems these don't run when the App is deferred.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the `name` and `after` properties of your initializers to setup this:

```
Ember.Application.initializer({
  name: 'init_socket',

  initialize: function (container, application) {
    application.deferReadiness();
     // your socket init code here
     //...
  }
});


Ember.Application.initializer({
  name: 'init_session',

  after: 'init_socket',

  initialize: function (container, application) {
     // your session system init code here
     // ...
    application.advanceReadiness();
  }
});
```

This way, your `init_session` will wait for `init_socket` to finish, while the overall application launch only at the end of `init_session`.

**UPDATE**

You can see here a live example: http://jsbin.com/zagejo/1/

I load users in the store, from two different arrays, one after the other between `deferReadiness()` and `afterReadiness()`.

Finally, the FIXTURES are loaded once the application has started.

```
Ember.Application.initializer({
  name: 'first_load',

  initialize: function (container, application) {
    application.deferReadiness();
    var store = container.lookup('store:main');
    store.pushMany('user', firstLoad);
  }
});


Ember.Application.initializer({
  name: 'second_load',

  after: 'first_load',

  initialize: function (container, application) {
    var store = container.lookup('store:main');
    store.pushMany('user', secondLoad);
    application.advanceReadiness();
  }
});
```

Comment: @Limestone this answer uses the `application` coming into the initialize function, so it's different then what you are doing, i.e. using the global..

Comment: @Knownasilya I should have mentioned in my first inital post, I am using Ember-CLI which uses ES6 modules. I can use the deferReadiness(); and advanceReadiness(); fine, it's just if I put the advanceReadiness(); without an Ember.Object (init method) it doesn't work.

Comment: Just to add that your example above does solve the asked question. Thanks!

Comment: The Ember.Object may wait for the application to start to be effective. Anyway, glad you came up with a solution. You can update your question to show how to handle that with ES6 Modules.

Comment: Adding the 'after' (or 'before') property is the solution since that is how you define in which order initializers should be run. Then you can advance and defer readiness in the initializers independently. Tightly coupling the initializers by splitting the readiness reponsibility seems to me like a bad idea.